# Build some sort of workflow in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to build some sort of visual workflow in JavaFX. I want my application to have one main screen with the next and previous buttons, something like an installer. When a user clicks next, all the elements of the next screen appear in the same element. All previous choices of the user have to be saved. So when a user clicks on the previous button that all of his choices are still there.

How would I go on to do this?

I found these links on Google, but they don't seem to help me. Something like this is a bit the direction that I want to go, but the code in this tutorial isnt't really that good for scene's with a lot of elements.

Comment: Your links are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataFX Framework provides a Flow API that can be used to define workflows. By doing so you can simply navigate between MVC Groups by only using annotations or configurations. You can find some examples of the API here:

- http://www.guigarage.com/2014/06/datafx-tutorial-5/
- http://www.guigarage.com/2015/02/quick-overview-datafx-mvc-flow-api/
- http://www.guigarage.com/2015/01/datafx-tutorial-6/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with JavaFX in a while, but I'll start by saying I really hope you are using the JavaFX scene builder.

The way I would do it off the top of my head without going back and relearning JavaFX is to create a main window in the scene builder, and have a sort of central content display area, which holds another custom JavaFX container that contains the content you want to display, of which you can then create several of and swap out which one is being displayed programmatically.

Basically, create several smaller components representing each step or screen and display them programmatically in an owning container.

Comment: I am indeed using the scene builder. That makes things a lot faster to work with.

Comment: Let me know if you are unable to make this solution work, I may take some time later (quite busy ATM) to help you figure it out.